# Why not worked wsdl.exe?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, wsdl

I need create .cs from wsdl.

I use VS2010 and framework 4.0.

I click AddService Reference -> Advanced... -> Add WEb Reference -> enter url username password -> view: Web services found at this Url: 1 Service Found - -> change web reference name -> click Add Reference.

In folder Web References created MyService and two files item.wsdl and reference.map.

and nothing more had the, what do I do next?

**update:**
If I create Add Service Reference create file:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.239
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace MyBegunApi.ServiceReference1 {

}
```

**update2:**
wsdl:
http://www.2shared.com/document/2z8emR3Y/wsdl.html

Answer (score 1):

it did

```
your class is called ServiceReference1.WebService1 ( Default).
```

so later  do :

```
 ServiceReference1.WebService1 a = new  ServiceReference1.WebService1();
```

p.s.
if you want the regular old version you should do :

[image]

Comment: I do not have `ServiceReference1.WebService1` and ` ServiceReference1.WebService1 a = new  ServiceReference1.WebService1();`

Comment: please get me simple solution with wsdl classes.

Answer (score 0):

As you want the class file do go to Add service reference. Do provide the url of the service for which you want to add the reference. Give appropriate name to the service once discovered. Now in the service reference file you will get the service reference with the name provided. In that you will get class reference.cs . This class will have all the methods and logic implemented into the service. YOu can create objects of the class you got from this reference class file and can then consume it.

Thanks

Comment: I find it difficult to understand you, can give a step by step how to do the right thing. thank you

Comment: 1. Go to 'Add Service References' by right click on your project 
2. Add service address and Go. If your service is working, you will get the service in Services section with methods implemented in Operations
3. Give name to this service reference in Namespace textbox and click 'OK'
4. On clicking 'Ok' one service reference will be added in to the folder 'Service Reference'. It will have one reference.cs file and this file will have all the classes and methods implemented in to the service.
5. You can then create instance object of this classes and then use them further.

Comment: what are you providing in service address.? service call url or wsdl path? as your response shown in details don't return any code there might also be a case that your wsdl might have some error in it.